# Git "Please tell me who you are"

Tags: git, github

Recentemente eu criei um projeto no meu PC e estou tentando dar commit pro github, mas sempre aparece essa mensagem.

```
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'Tomas D'Alessandro@DESKTOP-01L85NP.(none)')
```

Preciso colocar o mesmo e-mail do github ?
Sempre que abro o app preciso adicionar essas informações, não teria como automatizar ?

Comment: Se utilizar `--global` só precisará fazer uma vez.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Preciso colocar o mesmo e-mail do github ?

Não. Porém, por segurança, dá para fazer com que o 
GitHub rejeite commits que exibam emails configurados como privados.

> Sempre que abro o app preciso adicionar essas informações, não teria como automatizar ?

A configuração só precisa ser feita uma vez. Se você ler a mensagem, usando a opção --global, você salva a configuração para todos seus repositórios.

Comment: Oi Ken. De onde você viu que o GitHub rejeita commits feitos por outro e-mail?

Comment: Me confundi sobre isso. Desculpas... Na verdade a opção é Block command line pushes that expose my email.

Comment: Pelo que entendo, vc pode utilizar qualquer e-mail, só precisa ter acesso ao repositório de alguma forma. Por exemplo, ter chaves SSH válidas.

Comment: Verdade. Me enganei sobre a configuração. Faz tempo que a fiz na minha conta. A situação é que existe uma configuração que rejeita commits que sejam feitos por seu e-mail privado do GitHub.